# wpf documentviewer to view different file formats?

Tags: wpf, documentviewer

I have a wpf application where the user can upload files with different formats (for now only pdf).  I want to use document viewer to let the user see what's been uploaded.  Is this possible?   If this is not possible, can you suggest an alternative?  If this is possible, is this a good solution for this?

Thanks,
Angela

Answer (score 0):

I am currently looking for the same thing : a way to display a pdf document in WPF. DocumentViewer seems targeted on displaying XPS documents. It may display other kinds of documents, but it looks like we should supply our own Document class for that purpose.

So I am going to try displaying my documents using an old workaround : displaying them in an embedded web browser. It is not a good solution in my opinion. Especially for we can not access much document properties using that method (document pages count, pages size, ...). But I do not find any other readily available solution.